# Add a condition to check if values in those two cells B11 and D11 is not blank and make it required

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
 function CheckIn() {
 var formS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("form");
 var logS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("log");

 var str = formS.getRange("B2").getValue();
 var values = 
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("log").getDataRange().getValues();
 **var values1 = [[formS.getRange("B11").getValue()]]; //required
 **var values2 = [[formS.getRange("D11").getValue()]];//required
 for (var i=0; i < values.length; i++) {
 var row = values [i];
 if (row[SEARCH_COL_IDX] == str) {
 var INT_R = i+1

 logS.getRange(INT_R,7).setValues(values1);
 logS.getRange(INT_R,8).setValues(values2);
 SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('"Checked In"');

 } } }
```

I'm trying to add a condition to check if values in those two cells B11 and D11 is not blank and make it required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to retrieve the value in cells B11 & D11, then use this:

```
var values1 = formS.getRange("B11").getValue(); //required
var values2 = formS.getRange("D11").getValue(); //required
```

Then you can check if both cells contain a value using this:

```
if ( values1 && values2) {
  console.log( 'both cells contain data' ); // and continue your processing...
} else {
  console.log( 'one or both cells empty' ); // and stop at this point...
}
```

Bear in mind that even a cell containing a single space will count as "data" for this. So, you may need to refine the above, depending on *exactly* what conditions need to apply. For example:

```
if ( values1 && values1.toString().trim() !== '' 
    && values2 && values2.toString().trim() !== '') { ...
```

To "*make it required*" you could simply stop processing any further from that point - but it does depend on exactly how that situation should be handled.